# Which relay do I need for 240V input and 5V output?

Tags: relay

I am putting together a [PIR system](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/579364/292873) and need a relay with 240V 13A, UK mains, input and a 3.3V output to go to a Raspberry Pi. The Raspberry Pi needs to listen for the presence of the mains PIR device. What type of relay do I need?

Just to be clear, I am not asking for any specific product recommendations, I just know nothing about relays so would appreciate a point in the right direction.

Comment: It needs to have a contact rating of 240 volts AC (or greater) at the RMS current you want to switch (or above). The coil needs to be rated for operation at 5 volts.

Comment: @Andyaka No, it's the other way around, OP needs to detect mains presence via GPIO.

Comment: @Andyaka, I think the relay coil is energised from a mains-switching PIR detector.

Comment: Yes, it's a follow up of that question : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/579364/how-do-you-use-a-mains-pir-with-a-raspberry-pi/579374

Comment: If the PIR device uses a triac with RC snubber you may find that leakage through the snubber may tend to hold the relay on when the triac turns off.

Comment: You'd not use a relay but an opto-isolator in that case.

Comment: by the way, GPIOS input of the RPi are 3.3V not 5V.

Comment: @Blup1980 good spot, thanks! Have amended the question.

Comment: Is this the type of thing I need? https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/272619019157

Comment: I think technically you are asking recommendations for a product purchase. But like Transistor said, we can't know if it is compatible with your PIR sensor, it might be a too small load depending on what kind of device in the PIR sensor is switching the mains.

Comment: That ebay item would likely work. As inexpensive as it is, I'd say just try it.

Comment: At a quick glance i’d be suspicious of the electrical safety of said ebay device.

Comment: @Justme I am asking for (as my bank says) information not advice :D I just want to know if I am on the right track, I am not looking for your personal guarantees on any particular products.

Comment: if you want to detect mains in a way that's safe for a noob. just use a phone charger and a resistive divider to make 3V from 5V.

Comment: @Kartman  what did you see in the quick glance? the only problem I see is that if is missing an enclosure.

Comment: Insufficient creepage clearance with the optos. Also no certifications. If you buy an Omron G2R relay, the datasheet has cerifications and they maybe printed on the relay as well.

Comment: @JamesGeddes Well, I don't know what types of electrical work you are allowed to do in your country without being an electrician, but please note the legal and safety aspects - you are about to actually buy a random ebay product that has no approval markings from any electrical safety organization and install it into use. So I won't give advice, but make sure you have information that you are legally allowed to do so and your insurance covers it if an unapproved self-installed gadget burns down the building.

Comment: use a power adapter instead of a relay ... almost any wall wart would do ... use a resistor divider on the output of the power adapter

Answer (score 1):

You could get a relay with a 240V AC coil, and contacts that will work at a low DC voltage.  Some relays may be unreliable when switching very low voltages and currents, because of the metals used on their contacts.

Alternatively, as mentioned in the comments, consider whether an opto-isolator would do the job better.  You would need a small amount of circuitry to drive it from the mains.

Comment: I agree that an opto is a good technical choice. But given the technical knowledge of the OP. I strongly suggest that he doesn't design anything that will be in contact with the main. Instead he should use standard, approved and certified, out of the box equipment